# Spring data + JTA transactions + JBoss7

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I use JBoss7 and EclipseLink over MS SQL db. I'm trying to add Spring Data to my project, but everything fails when repository method implementation is generated.
It tries to join current transaction and fails with "ARJUNA016083: Can't register synchronization because the transaction is in aborted state".

My Spring config:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${module.persistence-unit-name}" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" />
</bean>

<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW" />
</bean>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="myUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mixx</jta-data-source>

        <class>package.MyEntity</class>

        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss" />
            <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
            <property name="eclipselink.exception-handler" value="package.persistence.EclipseLinkExceptionHandler" />
            <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="package.persistence.EclipseLinkSessionCustomizer" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

It fails exactly in JTATransactionWrapper.registerIfRequired(UnitOfWorkImpl uow) when it tries to call (line 136):

```
((Transaction)txn).registerSynchronization(new Synchronization() {

    public void beforeCompletion() {}
    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        //let the wrapper know the listener is no longer registered to an active transaction
        isJoined = false;
    }
});
```

Does Spring Data work fine with EclipseLink and JTA? Is there a chance to use it in my project?